# How to store level of WiFi in ArrayList<Integer>?

Tags: java, android, wifimanager

I am working on Indoor positioning system with wifi fingerprinting in which I want to store level of specifics BSSID in arrryList I tried this code but it seems not to work

```
public class calibrate2 extends AppCompatActivity {
WifiManager wifimanager2;
Button cali;
Button reset;
//EditText Tx;
//EditText Ty;
TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
List<ScanResult> list;
Integer j,x,i=0;
ArrayList<String> Ap=new ArrayList<>();;
ArrayList<Integer> si=new ArrayList<>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calibrate2);
    Ap = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("ap");
    cali = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   // Tx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
   // Ty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    wifimanager2 = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    cali.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    wifimanager2.startScan();
                    list = wifimanager2.getScanResults();

                    for (j = 0; j < Ap.size(); j++) {
                        for (i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            if (list.get(i).BSSID == Ap.get(j)) {
                                si.add(list.get(i).level);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        for (j = 0; j < Ap.size(); j++) {
                            textView2.append(si.get(j).toString());
                            textView2.append(" /n");
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
    );
}}
```

I guess the problem is in the for loop because activity is working perfectly but whenever I click button it goes to parent activity

Comment: You have added same for loop inside your main for loop `for (j = 0; j < Ap.size(); j++)`

Comment: yes because I want it in exact same order of that of Ap

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer now with this changes it is working

```
    `                   for (i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        if (Ap.get(j).contains(list.get(i).BSSID) {
                            si.add(list.get(i).level);
                            break;}}
                      for (j = 0; j <si.size(); j++) {
  //change Ap.size()to si.size()
                        textView2.append(si.get(j).toString());
                        textView2.append(" /n");}
```